# population matrix combinations SQL teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have this data set, basically customer_id, Brand, Indicator of 1 yes, 0 no (they are in that brand or not).  Well the dataset is made up kind of course... but it is in this 3 column format...

```
customer_id, brand, yes/no (1 yes, 0 no)
123, Sony, 1
123, Pepsi, 1
123, BMC, 1
123, Samsung, 1

122, Sony, 1
122, BMC, 1

125, Sony, 1
125, Pepsi, 1
```

basically, I need to get a count of all the Brand per customer groups, and find all the possible combinations and report it in a matrix, if you think of a correlation matrix, where you see all of these possible combinations, but with population counts, that's what I am basically looking for.

```
        SONY, PEPSI, BMC, SAMSUNG
SONY      3     2     2     1
PEPSI     2     2     2     1    
BMC       2     2     2     1
SAMSUNG   1     1     1     1
```

so I need to generate some kind of a Matrix of these intersections at the Brand Group level but comparing and counting the customers in those groups, I hope this makes sense.  I looked at some Combination SQL, and that seemed like it got me close, but wasn't counting the customers correctly, so I am a little bit stumped.  I am on Teradata 16, but any ANSI SQL that would accomplish this, as long as it works...  THANK YOU!

Comment: I don't understand how to related your expected correlation matrix with the actual sample data you provided.

Comment: did I do that wrong ? but basically, I need a matrix with counts, matrix-like..

Comment: Pepsi to Sony has a value of 2.  Can you explain how to read that data?

Comment: so 2 customers who bought Sony, also bought 2 Pepsi... I want to count the customer populations within the Brands.. basically how many customers who bought Brand A, also bought B - and so on...

Comment: I don't know if you can get this out of Teradata's pivot function.  To me this is something that should be handled in a front end tool.

Comment: Looks like a pivoted collaborative filter (which is not yet ported to the SQL Engine) https://docs.teradata.com/r/oiNzkhcE_qVAmLCtZuqZjA/22fBc3_YF3hYVbsyOFXo7w How many brands exist? Btw, the BMC/Pepsi value should be 1.

Comment: thanks! I will take a look at that link, the Brands are fictional, in real life it's something completely different, but I needed a fake example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btw, I figured it out... it's not in a Matrix format, but does give me all the Permutations, comparing when a customer spends Greater than $25 in each brand, against all of its possible combinations:

```
SELECT 
    count(customer_id) AS Counts,
    BRAND1,
    BRAND2,
    BRAND3,
    BRAND4,
    BRAND5,
    
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
         customer_id, 
        ,CASE WHEN BRAND1 > 25 THEN 1 END AS BRAND1
        ,CASE WHEN BRAND2 > 25 THEN 1 END AS BRAND2
        ,CASE WHEN BRAND3 > 25 THEN 1 END AS BRAND3
        ,CASE WHEN BRAND4 > 25 THEN 1 END AS BRAND4
        ,CASE WHEN BRAND5 > 25 THEN 1 END AS BRAND5
    
    FROM Table
    ) AS A

group by 2,3,4,5,6
order by 1 desc,2,3,4,5,6
```